# Laravel: How to store Excel File in a given path?

Tags: php, html, excel, laravel, export

I have a function which is converting my blade view into Excel format and downloading it. Now I want to save it in a specified location, i.e: public/uploads/release
Here is my controller:

```
 public function export_release()
{
    return Excel::download(new ReleaseExportView(), 'release.xlsx');
}
```

This function downloads the excel file downloads folder. I want to save it in the location: public/uploads/release

Here is my route:

```
Route::Get('outbounds/export_release' ,'outboundController@export_release')->name('outbounds.export_release');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `store` method to store the file in the filesystem.

From the [docs](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/store.html):

> Exports can easily be stored on any filesystem that Laravel supports.

**Default disk**

```
public function storeExcel() 
{
    // Store on default disk
    Excel::store(new InvoicesExport(2018), 'invoices.xlsx');
}
```

**Custom disk**

```
public function storeExcel() 
{
    // Store on a different disk (e.g. s3)
    Excel::store(new InvoicesExport(2018), 'invoices.xlsx', 's3');
    
    // Store on a different disk with a defined writer type. 
    Excel::store(new InvoicesExport(2018), 'invoices.xlsx', 's3', Excel::XLSX);
}
```

Now ideally you would store the file in `storage/app/public/uploads/release` and create a symlink from `public/storage/` to `storage/app/public` as explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk).

But if you really want to store it in `public/uploads/release` you could create new custom disk in `config/filesystems.php`. Something like:

```
'real_public' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => public_path(),
    'url' => env('APP_URL'),
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

Then you could use the custom disk to store the file:

```
public function export_release()
{
    Excel::store(new ReleaseExportView(), 'uploads/release/release.xlsx', 'real_public');
}
```

Comment: Error
Undefined class constant 'XLSX'

Comment: Which Excel class did you import? Maybe try without specifying the file reader, I updated my answer.

Comment: just needed to include this: \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::XLSX

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new storage disc in config/filesystems.php:

```
'excel_uploads' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => public_path() . '/uploads/release',
],
```

And store files like this:

```
Storage::disk('excel_uploads')->put($path, $file_content)
```